# Behavior of WHERE clause on a primary key field

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select * from table where username="johndoe"
```

In Postgres, if username is not a primary key, I know it will iterate through all the records.

But if it is a primary key field, will the above SQL statement iterate through the entire table, or terminate as soon as username is matched. In other words, does "where" act differently when it is running on a primary key column or not?

Comment: Why do you have a column named `johndoe`? For details on how the databases uses an index, you might want to read http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: 'johndoe' is not a column. 'username' is a column. 'johndoe' is an entry into the column

Comment: `"johndoe"` is an identifier (=column), `'johndoe'` would be a string value

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never knew double and single quotes meant different in SQL

Comment: @KeyurPanchal: no it will not. If there is an index, the database will use that index to find the row.

Comment: @AayushKarki: see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @KeyurPanchal: that is hardly iterating through the **whole** table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary keys (and all indexed columns for that matter) take advantage of indexes when those column(s) are used as filter predicates, like `WHERE` and `JOIN...ON` clauses.

As a real world example, my application has a table called `Log_Games`, which is a table with millions of rows, `ID` as the primary key, and a number of other non-indexed columns such as `ParsedAt`.  Compare the below:

**INDEXED QUERY**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM "Log_Games"
WHERE "ID" = 792046
```

**INDEXED QUERY PLAN**

```
Index Scan using "Log_Games_pkey" on "Log_Games"  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=4190) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ("ID" = 792046)
Planning time: 1.059 ms
Execution time: 0.066 ms
```

**NON-INDEXED QUERY**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM "Log_Games"
WHERE "ParsedAt" = '2015-05-07 07:31:24+00'
```

**NON-INDEXED QUERY PLAN**

```
Seq Scan on "Log_Games"  (cost=0.00..141377.34 rows=18 width=4190) (actual time=0.013..793.094 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: ("ParsedAt" = '2015-05-07 07:31:24+00'::timestamp with time zone)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1924676
Planning time: 0.794 ms
Execution time: 793.135 ms
```

The query with the indexed clause uses the index `Log_Games_pkey`, resulting in a query that executes in 0.066ms. The query with the non-indexed clause reverts to a sequential scan, which means it goes from the start to the finish of the table to see which columns match, an operation that causes the execution time to blow out to 793.135ms.

There are plenty of good resources around the web that can help you read execution plans and decide when they may need supporting indexes. A good place to start is the PostgreSQL documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html